# Which steps enable SQLite with Spring-Boot and JPA?

Tags: java, sqlite, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

To run SQLite with a Spring-boot (Version 1.2.3.RELEASE) application, I did these three steps:

1. use the SQLiteDialect class from [Spring boot and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232892/spring-boot-and-sqlite)
2. provide a JDBC driver; we used
   org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.7)
3. configure the datasource; here with a spring-boot .yml file:

   ```
      spring:
     datasource:
       url: jdbc:sqlite:<full-path-to-file>.db
       username: ...
       password: ...
       driverClassName: org.sqlite.JDBC
       ...
     jpa:
       database: SQLITE
       dialect: that.custom.SQLiteDialect
       hibernate:
         ddl-auto: update
   ```

Now, that's not enough. It ends with a "No enum constant org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database.SQLITE" error:

```
Field error in object 'spring.jpa' on field 'database': rejected value [SQLITE]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.jpa.database,typeMismatch.database,typeMismatch.org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.jpa.database,database]; arguments []; default message [database]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database' for property 'database'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database for value 'SQLITE'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database.SQLITE]
```

Indeed the *org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database* class has no SQLITE value, sadly.
However, the spring doc (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/Database.html) states:

> If a given PersistenceProvider supports a database not listed here, the strategy class can still be specified using the fully-qualified class name.

That looks like I have to:

1. remove the pointless

   jpa:
   database: SQLITE

configuration piece above, and

2. Provide some "strategy class" instead.

*Am I on the right path here ?*

*What do they mean with "strategy class" and how to get or implement it ?*

### UPDATE

Solution: According to the comment of M. Deinum, the right configuration reads:

```
       spring:
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:sqlite:<full-path-to-file>.db
        username: ...
        password: ...
        driverClassName: org.sqlite.JDBC
        ...
      jpa:
        database-platform: that.custom.SQLiteDialect
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
```

Seems like no "strategy class" needs to be implemented at all.
I've got it now: The removed `jpa: database: SQLITE` line (which corresponds to that *org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database* class) is not mandatory at all. It's a convenience way -- for most databases but not SQLite.

Remark: When using Hibernate, that `database-platform=...` entry is like `hibernate.dialect=that.custom.SQLiteDialect` in a Hibernate specific configuration, which would take the same effect.

Comment: rename `dialect` to `database-platform` and restart.

Comment: Following your suggestion (and removing `jpa:DATABASE:SQLITE` ) solved that indeed ! Great, that should eventually be an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hibernate the so called *strategy class* is a functional implementation of the `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` class. For the most common database there is a short cut and then you can use the `database` property and simply specify the database (like `ORACLE`, `DB2` etc.). However that doesn't exists for SQLite, you would need to configure the specific dialect.

To specify the dialect you can use the `database-platform` property and just pass the dialect to use to it.

```
jpa:
    database-platform: that.custom.SQLiteDialect
```

This also works for any other dialect like the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` if you want to specify a specific one for MySQL (for instance).