# spring boot hibernate with 2 sqlite database configuration

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, spring-boot

I have implemented answer from this question [Spring boot and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232892/spring-boot-and-sqlite)
and this is working fine, for single database.
But how to do configuration for multiple sqlite database.