# Executable JAR Bean creation - Not working

Tags: java, maven, sqlite, spring-boot, jdbc

Below snippet/code is working in Eclipse but When I build a executable JAR and try to run it, It displays the following error,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No add column syntax supported by org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        .....
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No add column syntax supported by org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        ....
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No add column syntax supported by org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
        at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getAddColumnString(Dialect.java:2088) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlAlterStrings(Table.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
```

DB Config -

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        //dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:sqlite:/C:/Projects/project1/db/sampledata.db3"); // working fine, when running through eclipse
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:sqlite:sampledata.db3"); // working fine when running through eclipse

        return dataSourceBuilder.build();   
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= com.example.demo.config.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.url = org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.database-platform= com.example.demo.config.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

executable jar - what db path needs to provided in this case ?

I have referred couple of them, tried to use :resource, but didn't work.  So any help is appreciated.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232892/spring-boot-and-sqlite might help you

Comment: I have already gone through that link. No luck

Comment: I highly doubt that this specific snippet of code produces that error. Please post the full exception stacktrace and a [mcve].

Comment: exception added